# Characters lost on simple assignment

Tags: arrays, string, powershell, variable-assignment, powershell-3.0

I'm having a very strange issue concatenating a simple string in powershell.

I have an array filled with integers (let's call it $countArray), and an array filled with strings ($reportMsg). I'm creating a description for a message using each of these elements, ending in a new line. This is done for each element in the number array.

```
$description= "`"";
foreach($num in $countArray){
    if($num -gt 0){
        $description+=[string]$num[$i] + $reportMsg[$i]+"`n";
    }
    $i++
}
$description+="`","

Write-output $description
```

The problem is that when I execute this, only the first number is concatenated to the string. I am 100% sure all of the values in the $num array are assigned. In PowerShell ISE's debugger, it even shows that $num has a value, it's just not assigned to $description.

Desired output:

```
"10 - apples detected
19 - oranges detected
4 - bananas detected
100 - guavas detected",
```

Current output:

```
"10 - apples detected
 - oranges detected
 - bananas detected
 - guavas detected",
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Without knowing exactly what's in those arrays it's hard to tell, but I suspect that this:

```
$description+=[string]$num[$i] + $reportMsg[$i]+"`n";
```

should be

```
$description+=[string]$num + $reportMsg[$i]+"`n";
```